# jQuery Mobile panel - check if it is open

Tags: jquery, mobile, panel

I'm trying to check if my panel is open or closed.

I tried like this:

```
$(document).on('open', '.ui-panel', function(){
   console.log('open');     
})
```

but nothing happens.

How I can set up an event listener for jQ mobile panel?

Open isn't a problem, cause I'll just add `.panel('open')` to button click and then `console.log()`, but what with close? Panel will close when I'll click outside, how to catch that moment?

Comment: You should have posted the answer as an "answer" instead of overwriting the original question. Now this question makes no sense anymore.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer.

Comment: I'm so sorry. If I remember there was problem with adding an answer to my own question. I repaired it now. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16513358/4277630 that is perfect solution for me!!! 10x Kal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, I found this:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#event-beforeclose

So what I needed was:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "panelbeforeclose", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

Answer (score 11):

What you need is to check if the panel opened or closed using `hasClass`

```
if( $(".ui-panel").hasClass("ui-panel-open") == true ){
   alert("OPENED");
}else{
   alert("CLOSED");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).bind('panelopen', function (e, data) {
        $('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
    });

    $(document).bind('panelclose', function (e, data) {
        $('body').css("overflow", "auto");
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I use like this:

```
if ($("#id").find("div").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
    alert("Closed");
} else {
    alert("Opened");
}
```

Comment: This will not always work as sometimes "visibillity" is not set to hidden but "overlay" is.

Answer (score 1):

For a *check now* check I used the following code.

```
function isSideNavVisible() {
    var sidenav = $("#sidenav");
    var sideNavHidden = sidenav.css("visibility") == "hidden" || sidenav.css("overflow-x") == "hidden" || sidenav.css("overflow-y") == "hidden";
    return !sideNavHidden;
}
```

If you can I would prefer to bind to the events as shown in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function OpenPanel(panel) {
    if ( $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
        $(panel).panel("open");

    }else{
        $(panel).panel("close");
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div onclick='OpenPanel("#ui-panel1");'>Click Here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want the pagebeforehide or pagehide event.

[See here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html) for jquerymobile event info.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS JQM applies to the panel explicitly indicates its state. Here's a very simple vanilla JS solution:

```
1 var document.getElementById("name-of-panel") = my_panel;
2 my_panel.classList.contains("ui-panel-open");
```

Line 2 returns "true" if it's open, "false" if it's not. It's also a lot easier for the next dev (or yourself in a few months) to figure out what you were doing.